# Programatically click a row in a listbox

Tags: ms-access-2013

When I click the a command button to close the form, the code requery's a cbo and listbox, moves the focus to the lstbox and a particular row.  What I need to do is add some code that "clicks" the current row in the listbox that has the focus.

Here is the code I have on the click event.

```
If Forms![frmmain]![txtHidden] = "addok" Then
Forms![frmmain]![cboAuthor].Requery
Forms![frmmain]![LstAuthor].Requery
Forms![frmmain]![LstAuthor] = Me.AuthorID
Forms![frmmain]![txtHidden] = "AddDone"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmAddAuthorFly"
Forms![frmmain]![cboAuthor].Requery
Forms![frmmain]![LstAuthor].Requery
Forms![frmmain].[LstAuthor].SetFocus
<NEED TO INSERT SOMETHING HERE TO CLICK THE ROW"

Else
MsgBox "txt hidden is not addok"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmaddauthorfly"
End If
```

Comment: Hi Gustav.  Thanks for the pointer.  I had some code in the after update event that I was wanting to run when I clicked the row in the listbox.  I now have added that code directly to the cmd button and it works perfectly.  I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.  Again, thanks for your suggestion/answer.  Regards

Comment: Gustav, if you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A click does nothing by itself, but you may have some OnClick code that runs. To do so, just call the OnClick event.

But all this requiring - and indeed "clicking" - shouldn't be needed; it seems as if you need to rethink your concept.